# Why am I banned so long for a few downvotes?

Tags: support, rate-limiting

One question was perceived to be improperly tagged, when in reality I couldn't mention what related to the tag at all because of the automatic filter.

Another was deserved but only made it to -5 anyway, 7 days is too much for that.

I need to ask questions and it's ridiculous that such a small offense gets a severe ban instead of anything else.

It's the least user friendly thing to do to completely bar someone from asking questions. Especially when they were legitimate questions and not spam.

Comment: There is no time for the bans.... it's a threshold you need to go OVER. So you need to edit your bad questions. Also, do you have any deleted questions?

Comment: Why act like bans don't exist? They clearly do. I am completely unable to ask simple questions because of two questions that weren't even spam.

Comment: I'm not saying there's no bans... I'm saying there's no TIME constraint for bans.... it's not a "oh you're banned for a week", it's "oh you're banned until your contributions go high enough to bring you over the threshold". I NEVER said bans don't exist.

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe If the most you can say for your questions is, "they're not spam" then that's a pretty low bar.  We expect questions to be a *lot* better than just "not spam".

Comment: What threshold? I can't find anything mentioning this in the "You have reached your question limit" message. And excuse me Servy that I'm not as elitist as you are.

Comment: Actually, there is a time-constraint *as well as* a ban, @Patrice - see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited

Comment: Well, posting [stuff like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29242273) certainly doesn't help your case or make it look like you're even *trying* to improve. Actually, it looks like the opposite. Try taking a break and coming back when you've calmed down.

Comment: Top tip: changing your username and About Me to whiny complaints won't endear you to anybody. *"I need to ask questions"* - but this community doesn't *need* to let you.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28224237/2564301) proves your (current) screen name is not appropriate. You also seem to be missing the [`Informed`](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) badge.

Comment: "It's the least user friendly thing to do to completely bar someone from asking questions." - I'm not sure it would be better to let someone wipe out their reputation since that's how you earn privileges on the site.

Comment: @BSMP - I don't think that would work. It would just mean more low quality questions as users would ask whatever they wanted, have it downvoted and closed, reach the ban, reset, repeat.

Comment: *"It's the least user friendly thing to do..."* - for the user that gets banned, perhaps, but **not necessarily for all of the other users**.

Comment: @TravisJ I think my comment was unclear. What I meant was that letting someone continue to ask bad questions until their rep reaches 1 is _less_ user friendly than a ban as soon as it's a problem. I was disagreeing with the OP that a ban is the least user friendly thing.

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe but the only reason you can participate in meta right now is because you still have enough reputation to do so. In your scenario, where you're allowed to keep posting questions that get downvoted, you wouldn't even be able to come to Meta for help on the site rules.

Comment: @BSMP the majority of my questions are not bad, majority of them are greater than or are 0. Downvote bad questions sure, delete them sure, but don't revoke my ability to ask based on only TWO questions

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe majority greater than 0? In your profile : 2 at 0, 2 over 0. That doesn't mean majority greater than 0 (and that's not mentioning the 2 deleted downvoted questions). Honestly, I know it can be frustrating... but instead of raging, take what ppl have said here to heart, and improve :). Yes the community is harsh sometimes, but it's with that that Stack managed to be what it is today... so all in all I think it's a good thing

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe I see below that you took offense to the phrase "high quality questions". Did you click on any of the links to the site tour or "How to ask questions" that are in the comments or answers? Because "high quality questions" wasn't intended as snark, that's just how the site refers to good questions.

Comment: @Patrice "What it is today"? This site has proven to be terrible. The only reason I got half of my downvotes was because of the automatic filter not allowing me to write my question with the clarity I intended.

Comment: That... seems very unlikely. If you have *proof* of the filter preventing you from posting a "clear" question, by all means take it to Meta.

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe As I said in my comment where I was getting aggravated (rewritting now for a calmer approach)... Why did you come to Stack in the first place? Because it's known to be the best site of it's kind? THAT'S "what it is today". In any case, if there was a problem with the filter making your question unclear.... Why is it the first time you mention it?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I didn't think to take a screenshot of it, but it did happen. I tried to name two files needed for use by OpenGL and it would tell me "this is not valid" And Partice it's not the first time I mentioned it. I mentioned it in the finished question. Hell even here I can't put an @ after Patrices name because of this arbitrary filter.

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe if that **was** the case, rather than write a question you knew to be poor, why not raise it on Meta or seek help in Chat? Note that you can only have one @ reply per comment - see e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45273/248731 (and bear in mind that just because you consider something to be arbitrary **does not make it so**).

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe if you believe that this question is **not** a duplicate, please edit it to clarify precisely how it is different - don't just add meta-commentary into it. And please watch the language, there's really no need for it. As for *"what is MINE"*; once you post it on SE, it is licensed to the network - see http://stackexchange.com/legal.

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe *"Stop fucking editing my sh it. It's my shit and not yours to edit. Learn your fucking place."* - charming! Also: factually inaccurate.

Comment: @jonrsharpe and I was about to comment that he seemed to be getting less aggravated in his answers... until I checked why this was getting edited so often.... now I'm sad

Comment: This is clearly not helping; I've asked the asker to take a short break.

Comment: Well, if none of us ever help you, why are you here?

Comment: @MartinJames there isn't much point in asking the OP anything for another week...

Comment: @jonrsharpe with that 'tude, a decade would be to soon.

Comment: As for the username - no, we are not obliged to help you in any way.

Comment: And, having once again proven to be working correctly, the system retires to its stately mansion to rest and relax before it must emerge again to ban assholes from shitting up the place.

Answer (score 27):

> Why am I banned so long for a few downvotes?

To prevent you from asking more low quality questions on the site and, as a result, consuming the time and energy of this community when you are apparently not able to provide contributions that are considered valuable.

> I need to ask questions

You might need to ask them, but we don't want people that are going to continually provide low quality contributions, whether they need the answers or not.

If you *really* need the answers, then it's worthwhile for you to take the time to ask quality questions that the site considers appropriate.

Comment: Only two of my questions are "low quality", the majority of them are well recieved. And what is "If you really need the answers, take the time to ask quality questions" if I really need the answers I need them now. Or more accuratley5 days ago.

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe Two of them have a positive score.  To are neutral.  You have some number of deleted questions (you mention two downvoted questions, so you have at *least* one deleted downvoted question, probably more).  So at *most*, 1/3 of your questions have a positive score (not anywhere close to "the majority"), but with a score of only +1, that's not a very high positive score on those questions either.

Comment: What the hell kind of site is this? "High quality questions". Do you want them to be served on a silver platter as well? It's not like I don't search first. I search everywhere I can for answers that even remotely resemble my problem. I go past the second, third, fourth pages of Google and when that fails, I come here as a last resort.

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe Then you've got research effort down better than other new users. Your next step should be [checking out this help center article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips to improve your current questions _and_ help you ask better ones in the future.

Comment: Spending a fair bit of time searching is certainly something that should always be done when asking a good question, but that alone is *far* from *sufficient*.  Spending some time searching doesn't make your question clear, reproducible, appropriately scoped, on topic, etc.  It's a good *start* (granted, farther than many others get), but that's all.

Comment: Being barred from asking any questions for several days also doesn't make my questions clear, reproducible, appropriately scoped, or on topic, but this site does it anyways.

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe You are banned so that you will realize that you're doing something wrong, to give you some time to improve your content (if you are successful, the ban/rate limits would go away) and also an opportunity to learn so that you won't continue to make the same mistakes in your future questions.  You now know what will happen if you continue to ask unclear/off topic/etc. questions, and so have an incentive to not make those mistakes again if you want to be able to continue posting.

Comment: The system is flawed extremely, and serves no purpose other than to promote elitism and punish beginners. Someone who did not write anything wrong, was downvoted to deletion just because they had a different opinion. I am not the only one who sees the problems with a site where any opinion, that does not conform to whatever minority of the site happens to see it, is deleted?

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe *"I am not the only one"* - well, maybe not, but we delete the others too ( < joke). *"The system is flawed extremely"* - literally millions of people disagree, but you're free to find a different system elsewhere. *"Someone who did not write anything wrong"* - the downvotes on your questions tell a different story.

Comment: _"...and serves no purpose other than to promote elitism and punish beginners."_ Let me just jump in and correct you here. There is no goal of "punishing beginners" here. I started on this site when I was brand new to programming, just out of college for networking. I have not once even seen a warning that I might be banned. My first question was a very basic beginner level question, but it was well-written and clear. The point is, _you can do it._ Just take a deep breath, maybe go grab a drink, and take your mind off the site for a bit. Then, come back and try fixing your old questions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I am not talking about me (and thanks for ignoring my point anyways btw) but someone else who commented here who DARED to disagree with you in saying the ban system was unfair.

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe the problem there **wasn't** the opinion (they're perfectly entitled to it, although calling something applied equally to everyone unfair is ludicrous), but the fact their not-so-cunning scheme for getting around the ban is in direct contravention of the [SE network TOS](http://stackexchange.com/legal). In fact, they deleted the post (and account, apparently!) themselves. Also, do note that Meta downvotes merely indicate disagreement - this is how the community establishes the guidelines. *[O/t, but if you leave out the `@` people don't know you're trying to talk to them]*

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe: You're not being forced to ask questions here, and no one is being forced to answer. It's all volunteer in both directions. If you find it useful, great, if not, then maybe it's not for you. Solution: adapt to the rules and stick around or decide to leave, either way it's a win-win for both you and us as either solution will lower stress levels all around.

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe If you really want to change the system, you have to make a real suggestion (be prepared for disagreement of course). Simply removing the rate-limits and post-bans isn't going to fly (we know how much crap is out there), so *make a real suggestion*. Just complaining about your case isn't going to win you much support.

Comment: Obviously don't remove rate limits and post bans but actually put some thought into them and don't just randomly press random numbers in the hope it will be balanced and fair. 7 days not for spam but for two questions that didn't live up to the ridiculous standards of this community.

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe You'd have to talk to Shog about that, he knows the secret algorithm (or at least he knows the people that do :) ). I'd have to agree with him though, a 7 day rate limit isn't the end of the world.  Do note that SE *does* tweak the algorithm when they find evidence of it being too harsh/lenient, so its not just random numbers.

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe if you haven't already, it's worth reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/248731. It's also worth avoiding inflammatory language like *"don't just randomly press random numbers"* and *"ridiculous standards"* (and, again, *"not spam"* is a **really** low bar!)

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe You also have 5 deleted questions, four of which were downvoted. Those count towards the ban as well.

Answer (score 27):

Seven days is nothing; some of us go months between questions. How? By learning to research our problems first: searching, reading, searching based on what we've read, learning enough about what we don't know to enable us to identify those gaps in our knowledge that need to be filled. Learning to debug our code, test our assumptions, and [narrow down our problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to one that others can identify and help us solve.

Seven days is not long enough to do these things. Seven days is barely a start. But seven days is what you have, for now - so do the best you can to use it productively. If you excel, then perhaps in the future the wait will be less than 7; if you do not, then it may well be more. What the future holds is up to you; go then, and make your future one you can be happy with.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that I did not try hard enough. Because clearly you know and understand my case well enough to make that assumption.

Comment: I know nothing about you, nor what you've tried. All I can see is what you've *done.*

Comment: And what is that supposed to mean? What does even remotely have to do with what I said or your original comment?

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe what do you mean *"What does even remotely have to do with what I said"*? You said *"clearly you know and understand my case"*, and Shog9's point is that **we don't need to** - all that matters is the quality of your contributions. If you've done lots of research, great! But we can't tell that you have if *it isn't in the question*. All the rest of us see is what you write.

Comment: His post is nothing about what I wrote only what he assumes I did

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe your title is *"Why am I banned so long..."*, and the question includes *"7 days is too much for that"*. This answer addresses that aspect of your question - the premise that seven days is some sort of draconian sentence.

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe Whenever I see people like yourself petulantly arguing the semantics of everything said, it makes me think *"If you can't take the time to write a clear and well formed question, maybe programming is not for you?"*. Programming requires clear logical thinking which is something you are not exhibiting right this moment.

Comment: I've finished what I needed to do 4 days ago. No reason for the length of this ban. Is everyone just an extremely slow reader? Is that what you assume? That it takes 7 days to read the ban message?

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe please **read the material you have been linked to**. Right from the very first comment on this question, it's been pointed out that the automated ban doesn't have a particular time limit. To quote [from MetaSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/248731): *"Automatic bans never expire or "time out." This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action, you will never be allowed to post again. **The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways.**"*

Comment: @jonrsharpe Actually, there is a time limit. See [Rolling question rate limits are now network-wide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243460/rolling-question-rate-limits-are-now-network-wide) and [Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot interesting, thanks. I didn't know that could go up to a week. With this constructive attitude, I'm sure the OP will be back to contributing in no time at all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's not in the main post, but [Tim Post's comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243460/rolling-question-rate-limits-are-now-network-wide#comment795941_243469) suggests that 7 days is the max (although it could certainly have changed since then).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot to be fair (being the user who first said there was no time limit) the time limit is linked to rate limiting, not full bans, no?

Comment: @Patrice that's correct, but I guess from the OP's point of view there's not much difference - either way, they can't ask their questions.

Comment: @NoneOfYouEverHelpMe Given that it still hasn't sunken in for you that you need to change your behavior and improve the quality of your questions if you want to be able to contribute here, clearly a shorter ban *wouldn't* have been sufficient.  If the ban would have been shorter, and as a consequence, not actually bothered you, then you would have no incentive to reform your behavior, and may not even have noticed that you were rate limited in the first place.

Comment: This site is a joke compared to perl monks.  I'm closing this account and heading back there.  Where people actually  help noobs, not this narcissistic Fiefdom of down voting and not helping beginners.

Comment: I am totally with you, G Alexander!

Answer (score 22):

It sounds like you've had a frustrating go at it. I'm not sure if another explanation will help, but I do want to take a stab at explaining why Stack Overflow is so picky about the quality of its questions.

First, **programming is hard** (you may have already noticed this), and following advice on Stack Overflow can be tough when you're starting out. [This](http://thecodinglove.com/post/60059719968/when-i-try-to-follow-an-advice-from-stackoverflow) [isn't](http://thecodinglove.com/post/57611651825/when-i-try-to-follow-an-example-on-stackoverflow) [new](http://thecodinglove.com/post/73325405396/when-i-try-to-implement-some-piece-of-code-picked), and I can guarantee that literally everyone on this site has been frustrated like you at some point (including myself). All I can do here is encourage truly understanding the snippets in the answers as much as possible, because things like variables etc may be renamed, and it's really easy to miss something simple.

Similarly, writing good questions that a fellow programmer can actually help you answer can be hugely difficult. This is why we have [so](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [much](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited) about how to ask them. **We selfishly want the questions and answers to be useful to other people in the future**, not just for your immediate need. This is why we close things that end up being, for example, a missing semi-colon.

I'd also like to take just a moment to point out that Stack Overflow is not a guaranteed answer machine - everyone answering questions on this site is volunteering their time to take a look at your questions (including this one), so although you may be frustrated with your particular problem, it still pays to be polite.

You seem to have taken some offense that people have commented asking for clarification, or that an answer might not work right off the bat. Especially when you're starting out, it can take a few stabs before you get to the real meat of what the problem was (like the accidentally set breakpoint in this [now deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091035/my-code-has-stopped-working-even-though-it-worked-before-and-i-had-made-no-chan)). And this is why it's a good idea to address what people have asked in the comments - they don't think that you're stupid, and they're not being lazy, they just don't yet fully understand your problem, and are asking for more context.

All of that said, you do run into the occasional snarkasaurus, and I've already edited one of the answers that was unduly so.

Note also that **deleted questions still count** towards stuff like question-banning, even though you may not see them on your profile anymore. Unfortunately I don't have better advice here than to be patient, and maybe take some time to go back and see if there is something you can improve.